# pyspark dataframe UDF exception handling

Tags: apache-spark, exception, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have written one UDF to be used in spark using python. This function takes 
one date (in string, eg '2017-01-06') and 
one array of strings(eg : [2017-01-26, 2017-02-26, 2017-04-17]) 
and return the #days since the last closest date. The UDF is

```
def findClosestPreviousDate(currdate, date_list):
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    currdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(currdate, date_format)
    result = currdate
    date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, date_format) for x in date_list if x != None]
    lowestdiff = 10000
    for dt in date_list:
        if(dt >= currdate):
            continue
        delta = currdate-dt
        diff = delta.days
        if(diff < lowestdiff):
            lowestdiff = diff
            result = dt
    dlt = currdate-result
    return dlt.days


findClosestPreviousDateUdf = udf(findClosestPreviousDate,StringType())
```

I am calling it like below

```
findClosestPreviousDateUdf = udf(findClosestPreviousDate,StringType())
grouped_extend_df2 = grouped_extend_email_rec.withColumn('recency_eng', func.when(size(col("activity_arr")) > 0, findClosestPreviousDateUdf("expanded_datestr", "activity_arr")).otherwise(0))
```

Even if I remove all nulls in the column "activity_arr" I keep on getting this **NoneType** Error. Tried aplying excpetion handling inside the funtion as well(still the same).

Do we have a better way to catch errored records during run time from the UDF (may be using an accumulator or so, I have seen few people have tried the same using scala)

ERROR:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 grouped_extend_df2.show()
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in show(self, n,
>   truncate)
>       334         """
>       335         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
>   --> 336             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
>       337         else:
>       338             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate)))
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in
>   **call**(self, *args)    1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1132         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1134     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:
>       321                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1111.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 315.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 315.0 (TID 18390, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177,
>   in main
>       process()   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172,
>   in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   104, in 
>       func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in
>   
>       return lambda *a: f(*a)   File "", line 5, in findClosestPreviousDate TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   iterable
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177,
>   in main
>       process()   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172,
>   in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   104, in 
>       func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in
>   
>       return lambda *a: f(*a)   File "", line 5, in findClosestPreviousDate **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   iterable**
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

Answer (score 0):

I tried your udf, but it constantly returns 0(int).

```
dlt = currdate-result # result and currdate are same
return dlt.days # days is int type
```

But while creating the udf you have specified StringType.

```
findClosestPreviousDateUdf = udf(findClosestPreviousDate,StringType())
```

Hence I have modified the `findClosestPreviousDate` function, please make changes if necessary.

```
>>> in_dates = ['2017-01-26', '2017-02-26', '2017-04-17']
>>>
>>> def findClosestPreviousDate(currdate, date_list=in_dates):
...     date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
...     currdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(currdate, date_format)
...     date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, date_format) for x in date_list if x != None]
...     diff = map(lambda dt: (currdate - dt).days, date_list)
...     closestDate = min(filter(lambda days_diff: days_diff <= 0, diff))
...     return closestDate if closestDate else 0
...
>>> findClosestPreviousDate('2017-01-06')
-101
```

Also made the return type of the udf as `IntegerType`. With these modifications the code works, but please validate if the changes are correct. PySpark udfs can accept only single argument, there is a work around, refer [PySpark - Pass list as parameter to UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906697/pyspark-pass-list-as-parameter-to-udf?rq=1)

```
>>> df.show()
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2017-01-06|
|2017-01-08|
+----------+

>>>
>>> in_dates = ['2017-01-26', '2017-02-26', '2017-04-17']
>>> def findClosestPreviousDate(currdate, date_list=in_dates):
...     date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
...     currdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(currdate, date_format)
...     date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, date_format) for x in date_list if x != None]
...     diff = map(lambda dt: (currdate - dt).days, date_list)
...     closestDate = min(filter(lambda days_diff: days_diff <= 0, diff))
...     return closestDate if closestDate else 0
...
>>> findClosestPreviousDate('2017-01-06')
-101
>>>
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> findClosestPreviousDateUDF = udf(findClosestPreviousDate, IntegerType())
>>> df.withColumn('closest_date', findClosestPreviousDateUDF(df['date'])).show()
+----------+------------+
|      date|closest_date|
+----------+------------+
|2017-01-06|        -101|
|2017-01-08|         -99|
+----------+------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for trying to help. The udf will return values only if currdate > any of the values in the array(it is the requirement). I have stringType as return as I wanted to convert NoneType to NA if any (currently, even if there are no null values, it still throws me NoneType error, which is what I am trying to fix). "pyspark can only accept single arguments", do you mean it can not accept list or do you mean it can not accept multiple parameters

Comment: Also, i would like to check, do you know how to use accumulators in pyspark to identify which records are failing during runtime call of an UDF.

Comment: `"pyspark can only accept single arguments"` means you can only pass the column of a dataframe as the input to the function, so it make your udf work use default arguments and pass the dates in that.

Dont use accumulators. It is anti-pattern in Spark and is deprecated. Refer : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/deprecated-list.html

Try exception handling and assign some return like "ERROR" in catch to find the the erroneous records.

Comment: `The udf will return values only if currdate > any of the values in the array(it is the requirement).` but the udf must return some value for each and every record.  return some value like "ERROR" or "NA and then filter those records which have this skip word as result. I guess that's why it says `NoneType` couldn't be cast to `StringType`.

Comment: **means you can only pass the column of a dataframe as the input to the function** . I am passing the columns only and it works fine in terms of parameters.

Comment: I think figured it out. I will share the modified function in the answers section. Appreciate you effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think figured out the problem. Here is my modified UDF.

```
def findClosestPreviousDate(currdate, date_str):
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    currdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(currdate, date_format)
    date_list = ''
    result = currdate
    if date_str is None:
        return date_str
    else:
        date_list = date_str.split('|')
    date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, date_format) for x in date_list if x != None]
    lowestdiff = 10000
    for dt in date_list:
        if(dt >= currdate):
            continue
        delta = currdate-dt
        diff = delta.days
        if(diff < lowestdiff):
            lowestdiff = diff
            result = dt
    dlt = currdate-result
    return dlt.days
```

The NoneType error was due to null values getting into the UDF as parameters which I knew. What am wondering is why didnt the null values get filtered out when I used isNotNull() function.

tried both

```
findClosestPreviousDateUdf = udf(findClosestPreviousDate,StringType())
grouped_extend_df2 = grouped_extend_email_rec.withColumn('recency_eng', func.when(size(col("activity_arr")) > 0, findClosestPreviousDateUdf("expanded_datestr", "activity_arr")).otherwise(0))
```

and

```
findClosestPreviousDateUdf = udf(findClosestPreviousDate,StringType())
grouped_extend_df2 = grouped_extend_email_rec.withColumn('recency_eng', func.when(col("activity_arr").isNotNull(), findClosestPreviousDateUdf("expanded_datestr", "activity_arr")).otherwise(0))
```

However when I handed the NoneType in the python function above in function findClosestPreviousDate() like below

```
if date_str is None:
    return date_str
else:
    date_list = date_str.split('|')
```

it worked.