# How use pyspark to modify all row of one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with more columns. I'm going to concatenate a phrase to each row of one column. For example:

```
         "date"                  "other columns"
2022-01-11 19:51:37+00:00              ...
2022-01-11 20:51:55+00:00              ...
```

I would modify all row of "date" cutting what comes next the hour and adding "00:00+00:00".
So text will become:

```
         "date"                  "other columns"
2022-01-11 19:00:00+00:00              ...
2022-01-11 20:00:00+00:00              ...
```

Comment: I am not sure about "concatenate a phrase to each row of one column" part but at least for normalizing the date, you can use `df.withColumn('date', F.date_trunc('hour', df.date))`

Comment: Do not working because it is a string type

Comment: It works with String column as well but if spark doesn't automatically convert it, you can cast before passing to `date_trunc` like `df.date.cast(TimestampType())`.

Comment: date_time='2021-08-01 00:00:17+00:00' comes converted in date_time=datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 2, 0). But the hour should be 0, while in the transformation is 2.

Comment: That is due to the timezone config.  If you have not have set timezone in spark config, it converts to your local timezone automatically.  To prevent it, I would use `.config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')` or truncate timezone information part.

Comment: Thanks, it working!

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to your title. You have already accepted an answer, that's enough to show other users that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Perfect, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that they are strings, you could do that using the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = (df.withColumn("date", functions.concat(functions.substring('date', 0,14), 
                                             functions.lit("00:00+00:00"))))
```

Comment: Don't use string functions when you can use datetime functions.

Comment: Thanks, it working. But I prefer to use datetime functions as suggested @Emma